# C child window procedure

Tags: c, windows, winapi

In C language, this is a child button window that I have put inside a window made with `CreateWindowEx()`. I am wondering if there's a way give this button window and ID so I can callback a procedure and make the button interactive for user experience.

Maybe implement it inside `WM_COMMAND -> switch(LOWORD(wParam)){ case: THEIDOF_BUTTON}`

This code runs under `LRESULT CALLBACK` window procedure of parent windows as you can see with `WM_CREATE`

```
HWND buttonBox;

case WM_CREATE:
(HWND)buttonBox = CreateWindow(WC_BUTTON, TEXT("ABUTTON"), WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_SIZEBOX, 500, 400, 300, 300, parentWindow, NULL, hInstance, NULL);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

read about *hMenu* parameter in [`CreateWindowEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632680(v=vs.85).aspx)

> A handle to a menu, **or specifies a child-window identifier**,
>   depending on the window style .. For a child window, hMenu specifies
>   the child-window identifier, an integer value used by a dialog box
>   control to notify its parent about events.

and from [`GetDlgCtrlID`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645478(v=vs.85).aspx) function documentation:

> An application sets the identifier for a child window when it creates
>   the window **by assigning the identifier value to the hmenu parameter**
>   when calling the CreateWindow or CreateWindowEx function.

so you need next code for create child:

```
buttonBox = CreateWindow(WC_BUTTON, TEXT("ABUTTON"), WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_SIZEBOX, 
500, 400, 300, 300, parentWindow, (HMENU)ID_BUTTON_BOX, hInstance, NULL);
```

where `ID_BUTTON_BOX` some integer value. and you get in back in [`WM_COMMAND`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647591(v=vs.85).aspx) as wParam (low word) or in [`WM_NOTIFY`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775583(v=vs.85).aspx)

---

here exist thin point - the `CreateWindow[Ex]` accept the `LONG_PTR` in place `hMenu` as child-window identifier. so 64-bit value on x64 system. the same result will be if call [`SetWindowLongPtr`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644898(v=vs.85).aspx) with `GWLP_ID`. we can call `GetWindowLongPtr(buttonBox, GWLP_ID)` after create and check that it return exactly `ID_BUTTON_BOX`. but if use [`GetDlgCtrlID`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645478(v=vs.85).aspx) function - it return `(int)ID_BUTTON_BOX` - truncated to 32-bit id.

in case [`WM_NOTIFY`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775583(v=vs.85).aspx) despite *idFrom* from [NMHDR](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775514(v=vs.85).aspx) structure declared as `UINT_PTR` here really only truncated to 32-bit id because the `GetDlgCtrlID` used for initialize it.

the `WM_COMMAND` at all truncate id to low 16 bit in *wParam*.

so for example if we define `ID_BUTTON_BOX` as `0x9012345678` when calling the `CreateWindow` or `CreateWindowEx` function - we got back exactly `0x9012345678` if call `GetWindowLongPtr(buttonBox, GWLP_ID)`. but `GetDlgCtrlID(buttonBox)` return already `0x12345678` only. also the `0x12345678` will be in *wParam* and *idFrom* when we handle [`WM_NOTIFY`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775583(v=vs.85).aspx) and on [`WM_COMMAND`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647591(v=vs.85).aspx) we got only `0x5678` as control id.

so despite we can set full 64 bit value for child window identifier (say pointer to some structure casted to `ULONG_PTR`) and get it back as is in call `GetWindowLongPtr(buttonBox, GWLP_ID)` - in [`WM_NOTIFY`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775583(v=vs.85).aspx) and [`WM_COMMAND`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647591(v=vs.85).aspx) we got back only low 32 or 16 bit of identifier. because this usually used only 16 bit values for child id

Comment: I was looking for `SetWindowLongPtr()` function, found it. thanks sir!

Comment: I see, it's still interesting it uses `HMENU` as the variable type, but yes you're right it's a lot easier, i'll test it now

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the HWND for your button, you must call SetWindowLongPtr to set the button ID:

```
HWND buttonBox;
#define ID_BUTTON_BOX  (100) // or whatever you like, should be unique for the parent window.

//..
case WM_CREATE:
    buttonBox = CreateWindow(WC_BUTTON, TEXT("ABUTTON"), WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_SIZEBOX, 500, 400, 300, 300, parentWindow, NULL, hInstance, NULL);
    SetWindowLongPtr(buttonBox, GWL_ID, (LONG_PTR)ID_BUTTON_BOX);
```

Here's a link to the MSDN doc: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644898(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: While possible, this is certainly not the standard procedure to assign an ID to a control. More commonly, the control ID is passed into the call to `CreateWindow[Ex]`, or statically assigned in a resource script. `SetWindowLongPtr` is really only useful, in case you need to *change* the control ID (which is rare in itself).